# Will saved images have tag properties with them when I load them back?

Tags: iphone, persistence, uiimageview, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I have 3 `UIImageViews`, and they all have tags 1, 2, 3, and are inside of an `NSMutableArray`. I want to save the images to a file upon termination of the app, then load them back whe the app loads and extract them from the array, and still have them have the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would persist the UIImage object, but the tag is in the UIImageView object.

I would recommend handling the tag separately. For example, you could store it as part of the file name and then restore it when loading the images.

Comment: How would I save the tag as part of the file name. That would really be a LARGE help to me. Please!

Comment: The tag is just an integer: NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",imageView.tag];